# Prolog - Make two Instantiations Equal

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to Prolog so please bear with me.

Lets say I have the following:

```
foo(bar(a,b)).
foo(bar(b,a)).
```

Then I enter foo(X) as a query:

```
?- foo(X).
X = bar(a, b) ;
X = bar(b, a).
```

Prolog returns two instantiations of X to satisfy the query: bar(a, b) and bar(b,a).

Is there away I can make these two instantiations equivalent? Once Prolog instantiates X to bar(a,b), it won't instantiate it to bar(b,a).

So when I enter foo(X) as a query:

```
?- foo(X).
X = bar(a, b).
```

X was no instantiated as bar(b,a), because it's equivalent to bar(a,b). Is this possible to do with Prolog, or does it go against the fundamental principals of Prolog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first clause of `symmetry/2` deals with cases in which both `foo(bar(a,b))` and `foo(bar(b,a))` occur. I use the standard order of terms in order to return only the former. Notice that the use of `@<` would have falsely excluded results like `foo(bar(e,e))`.

The second clause treats cases in which either `foo(bar(c,d))` or `foo(bar(d,c))` occur.

```
foo(bar(a, b)).
foo(bar(b, a)).
foo(bar(c, d)).
foo(bar(e, e)).

symmetry(X, Y):-
  foo(bar(X, Y)),
  foo(bar(Y, X)),
  X @=< Y.
symmetry(X, Y):-
  foo(bar(X, Y)),
  \+ foo(bar(Y, X)).
```

Example of usage:

```
?- symmetry(X, Y).
X = a,
Y = b ;
X = Y, Y = e ;
X = c,
Y = d ;
false
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Identity of literals it's the core of unification - the fundamental operation of Prolog algorithm - and then the answer to your question it's no, it's not possible to handle bar(a,b) as bar(b,a).